# What happens if I kill Fillianore in the Ringed City?

Tags: dark-souls-3

In the new Dark Souls III DLC - the Ringed City - you touch some egg to get to the final boss. The woman holding the egg is breathing and is called Fillianore. If I whack her, will she die? I'm too scared to attack her in case I break anything, but I really want to know what happens if you do kill her or if you even can.

Comment: What is dead, may never die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Filianore), she's not killable.

Besides,

> When you approach her and are moved to the next area, she's already long dead.